# Getting Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting Parameter count mismatch exception:

> Getting Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.

Code:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            ArrayList CustomerList = new ArrayList();
            CustomerList.Add("Robinson");
            CustomerList.Add("Pattison");
            CustomerList.Add("Todd");

            object[] obj = (object[])CustomerList.ToArray(typeof(object));
            Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Type customerType = executingAssembly.GetType("LateBinding.Customer");
            object customerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(customerType);
            MethodInfo method = customerType.GetMethod("printCustomerDetails");
            string customerObject = (string)method.Invoke(customerInstance, obj);
            Console.WriteLine("Value is : {0}", customerObject);
        }
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public string printCustomerDetails(object[] parameters)
        {
            string CustomerName = "";
            foreach (object customer in parameters)
            {
                CustomerName = CustomerName + " " + customer;
            }
            return CustomerName.Trim();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
string customerObject = (string)method.Invoke(customerInstance, obj);
```

...and the method:

```
public string printCustomerDetails(object[] parameters)
```

The input parameters (second) argument of this [`MethodInfo.Invoke(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload is an array of arguments, and your `printCustomerDetails` method has one argument which is an array of objects `object[]`, so you need to call `Invoke` this way:

```
method.Invoke(customerInstance, new [] { obj });
```

### Advice about ArrayList is outdated

Don't use `ArrayList`, it's from the .NET 1.x days. Since .NET 2.0, you need to use generic collections from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespaces (f.e. `List<T>`, `HashSet<T>`, `Queue<T>`...)

And if you need to create the array dynamically, I would suggest you that you should use `List<object>` instead of the outdated `ArrayList` to get full LINQ and LINQ extension methods support, and other improvements on list-type collections on newer generic lists since .NET 2.0 (old days too! Now we're in .NET 4.5).

Comment: @BhuwanPandey Check my advise about `ArrayList` ;P

Comment: Thanks for the advice so, I'll change it to                                        List<string> CustomerList = new List<string>() { "Robinson", "attison", "Todd" };
 object[] obj = (object[])CustomerList.ToArray();

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Your answer solved my TEASING problem that i was trying to solve for many hours. Read many articles and answers but none solved my issue. BIG thanks for you

Comment: @SyedIrfanAhmad Wonderful! I'm glad it has solved your issue! :-D